# Waiting for loop to finish with DispatchGroup getting data from firebase using Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, swiftui

I'm trying to get an array of employees and wait for it to finish.

Tried using `DispatchGroup` but nothing seems to happened.

There is two dimensional array the first one is over the employees, the second is on the documents that he successfully received. Then, it should append the `ShiftConst` object to the requested array.

I want it to notify when it finish by using the completion block ahead.

The results I'm getting is 0 and "didn't finished".

Here is my code:

```
    @Published var employeesConst = [ShiftConst]()

    func getAllShiftConsts(employees: [Employee], completion: @escaping (Bool) -> () = {_ in}){
        
        let group = DispatchGroup()
        var finish = false
        
        for employee in employees{
            let ref = self.session.db.collection(CollectionRef.users.rawValue).document(employee.uid!).collection(CollectionRef.shiftConsts.rawValue)
            
            ref.getDocuments { (qSnapshot, error) in
                
                guard let qSnapshot = qSnapshot, !qSnapshot.isEmpty else {return}
                
                for document in qSnapshot.documents{
                    group.enter()
                    do{
                        let data = try document.decode(as: ShiftConst.self)
                        self.employeesConst.append(data)
                        finish = true
                        group.leave()
                    }catch let error{
                        finish = false
                        group.leave()
                        print(error)
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
        group.notify(queue: .main) {
            completion(finish)
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
getAllShiftConsts(employees: session.employeesList) { finish in
            if finish {
                print("finish")
                print("Count: ", self.employeesConst.count)
            }else{
                print("didn't finish")
                print("Count: ", self.employeesConst.count)
            }
        }
```

After it finish I want to use it for this:

```
for (index, symbol) in self.date.weekDaySymbols.enumerated(){
            
            let day = Day(date: self.date.nextWeek[index], isSelected: false, hasShifts: false, daySymbol: symbol, dayNumber: self.date.nextWeekNumbers[index])
            
            day.setShifts(morning: self.session.employeesList, middle: self.session.employeesList, evening: self.session.employeesList)
            
            for const in self.employeesConst{
                if const.dateToString() == day.date{
                    for shift in day.shifts{
                        if shift.type == const.shiftType{
                            shift.filterEmployees(shiftConsts: const)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if index == 0 {day.isSelected = true}
            
            self.week.append(day)
            
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `notify` determines whether all `enter` calls it has encountered thus far have been offset by an equivalent number of `leave` calls. But your `enter` calls are *inside* the asynchronous `ref.getDocuments` call, and thus is undoubtedly reaching `notify` before it reaches the first `enter`. And, as such, it will fire off the `notify` block immediately, not waiting at all.

A more minor observation is that you are also using the group inside that `for` loop, but that’s not necessary unless you’re doing anything asynchronous inside that loop. So, unless your `for` loop is firing off additional async tasks, I wouldn’t entangle it with the group.

So, bottom line, call `enter` before your asynchronous call, and `leave` when that call is done (best achieved with `defer` in this case, IMHO).

E.g.

```
func getAllShiftConsts(employees: [Employee], completion: ((Result<[ShiftConst], Error>) -> Void)? = nil) {
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    var employees: [ShiftConst] = []
    var errors: [Error] = []
    
    for employee in employees {
        let ref = session.db.collection(CollectionRef.users.rawValue).document(employee.uid!).collection(CollectionRef.shiftConsts.rawValue)

        group.enter()
        
        ref.getDocuments { qSnapshot, error in
            defer { group.leave() }
            
            guard let qSnapshot = qSnapshot, !qSnapshot.isEmpty else { return }
            
            for document in qSnapshot.documents {     
                do {
                    let data = try document.decode(as: ShiftConst.self)
                    employees.append(data)
                } catch let error {
                    errors.append(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        if let error = errors.first {
            completion?(.failure(error))       // I don't know what you want to do with all the errors, so I'll just grab the first one
        } else {
            completion?(.success(employees))
        }
    }
}
```

A few other minor modifications in the above:

1. I’d suggest not updating `self.employeesConst` inside this `for` loop. You generally don’t want to have an asynchronous process updating model objects. You generally want a clear separation of responsibilities, where this function is responsible for retrieving an array of results, but it shouldn't be updating model objects. I would build the array as a local variable and pass the results back in the closure.
2. If a closure is optional, rather than default it to `{ _ in }`, you’d actually make it an optional, calling it with `completion?(...)` syntax. Personally, I wouldn't make it optional (so that the caller takes responsibility for updating the model), but I made it optional to match your code sample.
3. I don’t know what you wanted to do in the case of errors, so I just built an array of errors and supplied the first one in the `.failure` condition. Again, do whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and the explanation! it works now!
Quick question, is it not recommended to use this dispatch group method? because it blocks the main thread. is there a better way to achieve this goal?

Comment: @ElaiZuberman Because you’re using `notify`, you’re not blocking anything. Sure, there are other refinements we could suggest, but I addressed what I considered the substantive issues in my comments above.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this because you block main thread, making it unresponsive for everything, instead dispatch results asynchronously when ready, like

```
func getAllShiftConsts(employees: [Employee], completion: @escaping (Bool) -> () = {_ in}){
    
    for employee in employees{
        let ref = self.session.db.collection(CollectionRef.users.rawValue).document(employee.uid!).collection(CollectionRef.shiftConsts.rawValue)
        
        ref.getDocuments { (qSnapshot, error) in
            guard let qSnapshot = qSnapshot, !qSnapshot.isEmpty else {return}
            for document in qSnapshot.documents{
                do{
                    let data = try document.decode(as: ShiftConst.self)
                   DispatchQueue.main.async {
                     self.employeesConst.append(data)
                   }
                }catch let error{
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But this method would not let me use completion block when fetching is done.

Comment: Why do you need completion in this use-case? With approach like above your user will get some update in UI as soon as some data appeared, not at the finial end on completion.

Comment: Because I want to use this array after its done too loop again. I've added the work that I'd like to apply to this question.
I feel that this is the only way to accomplish what I need for this task. 
There might be a better way of course but right now this is what I thought would do it.